# WPF application crashed with XamlParseException and System.IO.FileNotFoundException?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I deployed my WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) application, it built as `32bit` application using .Net Framework 4.5.
I run the application on client machine (`Windows 7 64bit`). This machine installed `.Net Framework 4.5` and `Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013`. It crashed when launched.

I'm using Dependency Walker to profile it, and bellow is the log of DW.

---

```
Starting profile on 10/31/2014 at 4:58:32 PM

Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT/2000/XP/2003/Vista based Ultimate (64-bit), version 6.01.7601 Service Pack 1
Program Executable: \\tuyetam-pc\users\administrator\desktop\mystic server setup 20141025\mystic server v2.0 alpha (32bit)\MYSTICSERVER.EXE
Program Arguments: 
Starting Directory: \\TUYETAM-PC\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Mystic Server Setup 20141025\Mystic Server v2.0 Alpha (32bit)\
Search Path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Options Selected:
     Simulate ShellExecute by inserting any App Paths directories into the PATH environment variable.
     Log DllMain calls for process attach and process detach messages.
     Hook the process to gather more detailed dependency information.
     Log LoadLibrary function calls.
     Log GetProcAddress function calls.
     Log first chance exceptions.
     Log debug output messages.
     Use full paths when logging file names.
     Automatically open and profile child processes.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Started "\\tuyetam-pc\users\administrator\desktop\mystic server setup 20141025\mystic server v2.0 alpha (32bit)\MYSTICSERVER.EXE" (process 0xB64) at address 0x000C0000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "c:\windows\syswow64\NTDLL.DLL" at address 0x77E10000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "c:\windows\syswow64\MSCOREE.DLL" at address 0x71E30000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "c:\windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.DLL" at address 0x75800000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "c:\windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.DLL" at address 0x773A0000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x773A0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x773A0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x75800000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x75800000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
Injected "c:\users\administrator\desktop\depends22_x86\DEPENDS.DLL" at address 0x08370000.
DllMain(0x71E30000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\windows\syswow64\MSCOREE.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x08370000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\users\administrator\desktop\depends22_x86\DEPENDS.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x08370000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\users\administrator\desktop\depends22_x86\DEPENDS.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
GetProcAddress(0x75800000 [c:\windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsAlloc") called from "c:\windows\syswow64\MSCOREE.DLL" at address 0x71E36F3C and returned 0x75814EE3.

STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN encountered
Entrypoint reached. All implicit modules have been loaded.
Exited "\\tuyetam-pc\users\administrator\desktop\mystic server setup 20141025\mystic server v2.0 alpha (32bit)\MYSTICSERVER.EXE" (process 0xB64) with code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).
```

When I try to catch the Application Exception, the exception info is below

```
The error time: 11/2/2014 10:10 PM
Exception: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The invocation of the constructor on type 'DVRServerInterface.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CPPWrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
   at DVRServerInterface.MainWindow..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)___   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
InnerException.Message:Could not load file or assembly 'CPPWrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

Not that when I tried to install Visual Studio 2013 on client machine, and then the program was worked fine.

And more information: This is version 1.1 of my app

- In the previous version (1.0), I used VS 2012 and .Net 4.0, and I deployed successful version 1.0.
- In this version (1.1): I updated all project to VS 2013 and using .Net 4.5. So I don't know these steps caused the problem or not? I need to use .Net 4.5 for asyn/await methods.

Someone can tel me the problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried catching unhandled exception in application?

Comment: Are you sure your main window's xaml file is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'CPPWrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Indicates it could not load the referenced assembly 'CPPWrapper.dll'. Usually this means the file is not in the same directory as the executable file or in the GAC, or the versions expected and actual are different. This is also the case if a dependent assembly from 'CPPWrapper.dll' is missing.

Giving the name, the assembly is most likely a C++ wrapper assembly. That means that it might depend on external libraries or framework files (maybe even different processor architecture) as installed.

A useful tool to analyse dependency related issues is the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, I thought about these case, but the DW cannot show me the exactly the problem.

Comment: I tried to install Visual Studio 2013 on client machine, and the the program was worked fine. So I can not using Fusion Log Viewer to detect the problem. Do you have any suggestion for me. Thank you!

Comment: No, it makes clear that there is an installation component of VS missing. Maybe the right VC++ runtime or something like that.

Comment: I have installed .Net Framework 4.5 Full Package and Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013. Can you list the other components that VS have. I'm very tired with this issue on recent days, thank you very much!

Comment: It depends on version, operating system, etc. Maybe Reflector can be useful to determine the dependencies. I am sure you can download a trial.

Comment: Please read my recent update above for more information, thank you!

Comment: Sure you didn't introduce another dependency or another version of a dependency? If you compare the csproj file from then and now, does it show differences in the dependencies?

Comment: Can you explain more detail? What is "introduce another dependency or another version of a dependency"? and what is "compare the csproj file from then and now..."?

Answer (score 0):

Today, I tried to install more 2 components are:

1. Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2010
2. Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2012

Actually, this application started development since 2010 with VS 2010. And then I updated project to use VS 2012 and now is VS 2013.

I'm very happy when this way can solve my issue, but someone can explain me what happen?